# d3 + adding text labels + formatting

Tags: d3.js

this is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygmkvreb/1/), which I am building with from this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)

what is the best way to convert the text lables from 0.08 to 8% format.

This is my attempt, but is there a better/other way?

`.text(function(d) { return Math.floor(d.frequency*100)+"%"; });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way to do it (let's call it the "d3 way") is to use the d3 formatting functions:

```
var format = d3.format("%");
```

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cr91xf1t/

You can play with several built in formats, or even create your own. Have a look here: http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e

Comment: tk u that's is what I was looking for.

Comment: No worries! I just updated my answer, check the second link. I use it all the time.

Comment: I have a question here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/41385010/1735836) you might be able to help me with.